# How can I copy all of a worksheet, including pictures and charts to another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-interop

This is the same question [as this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019513/copy-worksheet-from-another-workbook-including-charts). However, the solutions in the post don't answer the question.

How can I copy all of a worksheet, including charts & pictures, to a new worksheet in another workbook?

And copy the formulas across too.

I need to do this in my AddIn - C# and using the COM (note VSTO) API to Excel.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

Move a worksheet within a workbook
Select the worksheet tab, and drag it to where you want it.

Note: Be aware that calculations or charts that are based on worksheet data might become inaccurate if you move the worksheet.

Copy a worksheet in the same workbook
Press CTRL and drag the worksheet tab to the tab location you want.

OR

1)Right click on the worksheet tab and select Move or Copy.

2)Select the Create a copy checkbox.

3)Under Before sheet, select where you want to place the copy.

4)Select OK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need to do this in C# using the COM API to Excel. thanks - dave